# Calculating all possibilities for a string with optional parts

Tags: string, algorithm, combinatorics

I want to generate a list of all possible combinations of a string that contains optional parts. This is probably best explained with some examples:

- `A[B]` → `A` and `AB`
- `A[B][C]` → `A`, `AB`, `AC` and `ABC`
- `A[B[C]]` → `A`, `AB` and `ABC`

I hope this sufficiently explains what I'm trying to do.

I could hack together my own little parser or "algorithm" for this, but I have a strong feeling that there's an existing (and easier) solution for this. Because I don't have any kind of CS education (yet), I have no idea what kind of algorithm I'm looking for or even just what search terms to use.

Is my hunch correct and is there actually an existing (well-documented) approach for this?

Comment: Don't know about existing algorithm, but if I had to do this I would build the graph for the pattern, expand the graph to a tree and then do a breadth first traversal.

Comment: I think this is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton.

Comment: What's the difference between "algorithm" and ""algorithm""? (Meaning, why did you place the word in quotes in the question description)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Good point, I used ""algorithm"" (with quotes) in the sense of: it fits the *definition* of an algorithm, but it isn't "smart" or "efficient" in any way. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @NeilEdelman That does look similar, but I'm not sure how I could apply this to my problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @NicolasReynis As someone without any kind of CS-education this *sounds logical*, but I have no idea how to actually apply or implement this. Do you have any resources that could help me (better) learn these subjects?

Comment: The Wikipedia entry is kind of high-level, but this is one implementation, https://re2c.org/manual/manual.html#regular-expressions. Your rules would be mapped in `re2c` as, `A[B] -> AB?`, `A[B][C] -> AB?C?`, `A[B[C]] -> A(BC?)?`. Arguably the most famous is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the article but it seems that this question have been studied. There's an article page 117: "Enumeration of Formal Languages" http://www.eatcs.org/images/bulletin/beatcs89.pdf

You may find more on this subject by searching with the good keywords like "enumerate language for DFA"

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm could be like the following:

```
- Parse the string and make a rooted binary tree that on each node breaks on 
the new bracket exists or not.

- You can go through the root to the leaf of the tree.
  All paths from the root to leaves generate all combinations.
```

Also you can use a push-down automaton to parse the string for knowing where a bracket is opened and where it is closed. There are many implementations for the case that you can find.

Comment: This approach is very similar to what I managed to come up with myself. What would be an efficient way to generate the tree?

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey you can use a push-down automaton to parse the string for knowing where a bracket is opened and where it is closed. There are many implementations for the case that you can find.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something in JavaScript, only tested for the three examples provided. Hopefully the (attempted) recurrence is clear from the code:

```js
function f(string, index, combinations){
  if (index == string.length)
    return [combinations, index]
    
  if (string[index] == "["){
    let prefixes = []
    let [suffixes, nextIndex] = f(string, index + 1, [""])

    for (let combination of combinations)
      for (let suffix of suffixes)
        prefixes.push(combination + suffix)

    if (nextIndex == string.length)
      return [combinations.concat(prefixes), nextIndex]
    else
      return f(string, nextIndex, combinations.concat(prefixes))
    
  } else if (string[index] == "]"){
    return [combinations, index + 1]
    
  } else {
    for (let i=0; i<combinations.length; i++)
      combinations[i] += string[index]
    return f(string, index + 1, combinations)
  }
}

strings = [
  "A[B]",
  "A[B][C]",
  "A[B[C]]"
]

for (let string of strings)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(f(string, 0, [""])[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The grammar you defined contains only 2 different entities: Terminals (a character) or an Optional part of the grammar.

In the Haskell code below, this is reflected by the definition of the discriminated union `Grammar`.

The first task is to convert a given concrete syntax (e.g. "A[B]") into a list of Grammar parts (each terminal or optional). In the code below, the function `fromString` does just that.

The interesting part, though is how to generate all possible strings for a given syntax.
In the code below, the function `generate` does this, recursively.

- For an empty grammar list (which is the end of the recursion), the output is a single empty string.
- If a terminal symbol is found in the grammar list at a given position, the respective character is pasted in front of all variations, generated from the remainder of the grammar list.
- If an optional part is found in the grammar list, the list of the remainder of the grammar list is yielded twice; once with the optional part prepended and once without.

For the non-functional people reading this, it should be pointed out that `fmap` is a function which maps a list to another list (element wise). 
The other function I used in the code below, non-haskellers might stumble over is `concat`, which turns a list of lists into a list.

```hs
data Grammar = Terminal Char | Optional [Grammar] deriving (Show,Eq)

fromString :: String -> [Grammar] -> ([Grammar],String)
fromString [] acc = (acc,"")
fromString ('[':cs) acc = 
    let (o,rest) = fromString cs [] in
        fromString rest (acc ++ [Optional o])
fromString (']':cs) acc = (acc,cs)
fromString (c:cs) acc = fromString cs (acc ++ [Terminal c])

generate :: [Grammar] -> [String]
generate [] = [""]
generate ((Terminal c) : parts) = fmap (\s -> c : s) $ generate parts
generate ((Optional gs) : parts) = tails ++ (concat . fmap prependOpts $ tails)
    where 
        tails = generate parts
        opts = generate gs
        prependOpts :: String -> [String]
        prependOpts tail = fmap (\o -> o ++ tail) $ opts
```

Putting it all together in the REPL (interactive shell), running
`fromString "A[B][C]" []`, for example yields:
`([Terminal 'A',Optional [Terminal 'B'],Optional [Terminal 'C']],"")`

And if we run `generate` on the grammar list above (the first part of the tuple), we get all our strings:
`generate (fst $ fromString "A[B][C]" [])`
`["A","AC","AB","ABC"]`

Comment: This looks interesting, but unfortunately I don't know Haskell (at all) so I'm not a 100% sure I understand your concept (since I can barely read your code). I'll try to take another look at this tomorrow to see if I can decipher this functional-mayhem.